# Why need for 96kHz, 192kHz audio?

Tags: acoustics, frequency, signal-processing

Human can hear 20-20,000 Hz waves, so by [Nyquist theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem) it's sufficient to sample audio with 40 kHz. Indeed, 44.1 kHz widely used. But what do we need higher sample rates for? 96 kHz, 192 kHz are widely used too.

Comment: I heard it made a difference to go to higher frequencies e.g. 60 kHz (no pun intended) - wonder if it makes the waveform smoother to sample at a higher rate and this gives more faithful reproduction.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the benefits of a specific way of signal processing, which belongs on [dsp.SE].

Comment: @ACuriousMind, signal processing is part of physics, isn't it? If no, why there is the tag "signal-processing"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For general audio programming or playback, [96kHz or 192hHz is simply useless](http://xiph.org/~xiphmont/demo/neil-young.html).

Indeed, the [Nyquist theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem) tells you that a signal can be **exactly** reproduced given that the sample rate is greater than the highest frequency contained in the original signal.

The "excuse" of the slope of analog filter required after digital to analog conversion is no longer valid with today's converters. Nowadays, most converters use [oversampling reconstruction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oversampling#Oversampling_in_reconstruction) so that analog filters are no longer an issue.

**So why do we use higher sampling rate?**

The main point for higher sampling rate is just marketing: people still believe their intuitions on this matter.

In fact, this belief is so strong that some DSP console maker give the option to configure their input/output converters to work at higher sampling rate. Nevertheless, inside the DSP, the signal is always downsampled to 48kHz for several reasons:

- keep more processing power per sample,
- avoid having to recompute all the sample-rate dependent parameters (iir coefficients for example)
- avoid computational singularity issues at low frequencies.

*One valid reason to use a higher sample rate is to minimize latency, but this also sound like an excuse when the processing uses audio buffers containing several samples anyway..*

Answer (score 1):

because the higher the sampling rate is the sloppier the (annalogue) filtering preceding the sampler can be to reduce the aliased noise/interference